# Fastest Way to search in Gigabytes of data?

Tags: python, performance, memory

I have a cvs file of size 8-12 GB, and I would like to be able to search the first column of the file and retrieve the whole rows if there is a match. I would like to do the search for a set of more than 100K keys every time and retrieve the corresponding record for them.

There are a couple of approaches I can choose:

1) use a simple grep for each key in the file ==> 100K grep commands

2) make a SQL based database and index the first column then:
        a) search for each key by one select query.
        b) make a temporary table and insert all the keys to it and then do a set membership

3) make a hash function, such as Python dictionary and then search it by key. But I need to load it into the memory every time I need to do a bulk of queries (I don't want it to always occupy the memory)

I'm not sure which method is more efficient? Or any better options which I'm not aware of.

Comment: almost certainly a database or nosql keystore is the way to go... that said this is also almost certainly OT :/

Comment: Indexed database sounds like a good idea.

Comment: you should consider pyspark,it is optimze for such operations

Answer (score 0):

You can read chunks of the csv iterated using pandas. Perhaps this solution can work for you: [How to read a 6 GB csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution (if you have plenty of RAM) would be to just `mmap` the whole file.

What would certainly work is to read the file one line at a time:

```
# keys is an iterable of keys.
sep = ';' # The separator used in the CSV.
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        to = line.find(sep)
        if line[:to] in keys:
            # do something
```